# User and Employer Authentcation

Tags: react-native

I am currently studying more about react native. I am trying to find out how am I able to get an authentication for user and employer. The user has different screens and drawer navigation and also the employer has different screens and drawer navigation. User's screen can access some employer's data and vice versa. I am having a hard time finding this out please point me to the right direction on which I need to study more. Thank you very much! Also when logging in it will be able to determine if it is a "user" or an "employer"

Answer (score 0):

This needs to be done in back-end,
when you get response for login try sending a Boolean value for employer and based on this value show or hide the screens or navigate to different stack